# SimpleDateFormat Unparseable date Error if locale is ES. Twitter "Created_At"

Tags: java, android, twitter, locale, simpledateformat

I'm trying to convert the twitter "created_at" to an Argentinian Date-time.
If I do this:

```
final String TWITTER="EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss";
        SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat(TWITTER,new Locale("en"));
```

It works fine.

But if I change to `Locale("es")`, `Locale("es","ES")` or `Locale("es","AR")`,
I am getting this error:

> 07-01 11:09:29.153: W/System.err(331): java.text.ParseException:
>   Unparseable date: "Tue Jul 01 13:57:36 +0000 2014"

Why can't I convert the date to my local time?

EDIT:

Based on what Sotilios Delimanoris told me about using two SimpleDateFormat, one for parse and other for format, i've done this:

```
final String TWITTER="EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss";  
SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat(TWITTER,new Locale("en")); 
Date mystring = sf.parse(text); 
final String TWITTER2="dd-MM HH:mm:ss";  
SimpleDateFormat sf2 = new SimpleDateFormat(TWITTER2,new Locale("es","AR")); System.out.println(sf2.format(mystring)); 
return sf2.format(mystring);
```

This is the output:

> I/System.out(688): 01-07 18:41:31

Everything is ok, except for the hour, it's showing 2 hours more that what it should. –

I have tried setting time zone like this:

```
sf2.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC-3"));
```

And now it's even worse, it shows 22:41:31

EDIT2:

Finally, it's working. Don't know why, but using:

```
sf2.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-6"));
```

Works fine (still in argentina is not GMT-6)

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to parse the date string in what I assume is Spanish, but `Tue` and `Jul` are not short words in Spanish. They are short for English words.

Comment: so what should i do ?

Comment: @RedesConnectedGroup You would need Spanish date string, whatever the corresponding of `Tuesday` and `July` (and all the others) are. Also, I hope you understand that a date doesn't have a `Locale` or a language, so I don't see a purpose of what you are doing.

Comment: Im getting the date string from the twitter api, so i can't change that.

Comment: @RedesConnectedGroup If twitter is generating the date string in English, then you parse it in English. It makes no sense to parse it in Spanish.

Comment: Okey, i parse the string in english, but i need to display it in spanish, and with argentinian time. How should i do this ?

Comment: @RedesConnectedGroup If you want to reformat it, you `parse` it in English, and `format` it in Spanish. Use two `SimpleDateFormat` objects.

Comment: Ok. Im trying this now:

final String TWITTER="EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss";    
     SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat(TWITTER,new Locale("en"));   
     Date mystring = sf.parse(text);
     final String TWITTER2="dd-MM HH:mm:ss";    
     SimpleDateFormat sf2 = new SimpleDateFormat(TWITTER2,new Locale("es","AR"));
     System.out.println(sf2.format(mystring));
     return sf2.format(mystring);
This is the output: 
I/System.out(688): 01-07 18:41:31

Everything is ok, except for the hour, it's showing 2 hours more that what it should.

Comment: @RedesConnectedGroup Don't post code in comments. Edit your question and add it there.

Comment: @RedesConnectedGroup Check your timezones.

Comment: Just tried setting timezone utc-3 to sdf and its worst.