# Calendar returning birmanian numbers

Tags: android, calendar, simpledateformat

something strange happened. I'm using Calendar to name the audiofiles I'm recording. Everything was working ok until today. The next code is giving me the date in birmanian, I don't know why.

The code is simple:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();           
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);                       
SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH;mm;ss[,[dd-MM-yyyy");
String formatted = format1.format(cal.getTime());
```

(I'm using all the "; , [ and more strange characters to create the file after, it is not the cause of the problem it worked well few days ago)

what I'm getting is:

```
formatted = ၁၃;၅၃;၂၅[,[၃၁-၀၅-၂၀၁၆
```

Any help?
Thanks for your time!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SimpleDateFormat Unparseable date Error if locale is ES. Twitter "Created\_At"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24512751/simpledateformat-unparseable-date-error-if-locale-is-es-twitter-created-at)

Comment: Just use English locale for simple date formatting. Put attention on warning from lint

Comment: in format class:  In some cases these representations may be localized or contain localized characters or strings.